# React hitting api multiple times when usestate changes

Tags: node.js, reactjs

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import Axios from "axios";import { Link, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

import "../assets/css/login.css";import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";

import API from "../backend";
const Signout = () => {const [values, setValues] = useState({reDirect: false,});


const { reDirect } = values;

if (typeof window !== "undefined") {localStorage.removeItem("TWjwt");
const axiosGetCall = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await Axios.get(`${API}/logout`);
    // enter you logic when the fetch is successful
    console.log(`data here: `, res);
    setValues({ ...values, reDirect: true });
  } catch (error) {
    // enter your logic for when there is an error (ex. error toast)
    console.log(`error log: `, error);
  }
};
axiosGetCall();

}

return <>{reDirect === true ? <Navigate to="/" /> : <></>}</>;};

export default Signout;`
```

hello,

i'm trying to learn react and above code has no problem instead the code is hitting my backend api multiple times for single logout..

i have removed <React.StrictMode> but still it is hitting apis multiple times..

i have understood that when my state changes the code is running again and again..

so any solutions ?

Comment: Could you provide a working example? Or clarify the code snippets a bit (are they in one file, etc). I'm guessing you'll want to put the `axiosGetCall` into an useEffect to make it get called only once.

Comment: i have cleaned the code. can you post an example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
useEffect(() => {
    const axiosGetCall = async () => {
      const res = await Axios.get(`${API}/logout`);
      // enter you logic when the fetch is successful
      console.log(`data here: `, res);

      if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
        localStorage.removeItem("TWjwt");
      }
      setValues({ ...values, reDirect: true });
    };
    axiosGetCall();
  }, []);
```

OK- Issue was Solved...

[image: I'm getting 2 times api call for logout route]